# 2 Forms on same model not saving as same user - Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a questionnaire / survey, and have two forms (Model Form) built on the same model. These forms are called on separate views, but when saved they appear as separate users in the database. I'm not sure how to get them so save as the same user, I am already using the ' post = form.save(commit=False),   post.user = request.user,  post.save()' method to save the forms.

EDIT: Added in an attempt to save to the same instance

Model:

```
 class QuizTakers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    industry_choices = (
                        (1, 'Service'),
                        (2, 'Hospitality'),
                        (3, 'Wholesale/Retail'),
                        (4, 'Manufacturing'),
                        (5, 'Agriculture')
                        )

    industry  =  MultiSelectField(choices=industry_choices, max_length=1, max_choices=1)
    company_name = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Forms:

```
# Form for getting company name
class QuizTakerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizTakers
        fields = ['company_name']

# Form for getting company industry
class QTIndustryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = QuizTakers
        fields = ['industry']
```

Views:

```
# view for getting company name
def start(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = QuizTakerForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            request.session['company_name'] = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('industry/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = QuizTakerForm()
    return render(request, 'ImpactCheck/start.html', {'form': form})

# view for getting industry 
class IndustryView(FormView):
    template_name = 'ImpactCheck/industry.html'
    form_class = QTIndustryForm
    success_url = '1/'


    def get(self, request):
        company_name = request.session['company_name']
        this_user=QuizTakers.objects.filter(company_name=company_name).order_by('-timestamp').first()
        form=self.form_class(instance=this_user)
        company_name = request.session['company_name']
        return render(request, 'ImpactCheck/industry.html', {'form': form, 'company_name': company_name})

    def form_valid(self, form):
          # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
          # It should return an HttpResponse.
          post = form.save(commit=False)
          post.user = self.request.user
          post.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/1')
```

Comment: When you say **These forms are called on separate views** , do you know what order they are to be filled in? If you  have these form in different views, one of them must be responsible for creating the object and the other must be responsible for updating the stored object.

Comment: Hi @AkshathMahajan, thanks for your comment! The company name view is called first. By the object, do you mean the field in the model? Each form calls on a different field from the model, and both save the form that is created. I tried to tie the two together by using the 'post.user = request.user' before calling post.save()

Comment: You should take a look at form instances in django, that way you create the object in the company name view and then update that object in the next view.
By objects, I mean one rows in your database

Comment: I've added in an attempt to save to the same instance, by filtering on the instance with the same company name and most recent timestamp, and then adding that instance filter when calling the form. The views are working but still not saving to the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in your `def start(request)` function, you should consider adding the ID to `request.session` instead of the company name. Something along the lines of

```
def start(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = QuizTakerForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            form.instance.user=request.user
            form.save()
            request.session['obj_id'] = post.id

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('industry/')
```

Now you can use that id to get both the name of your company, as well as the object.

In your `IndustryView(FormView)`, if you're having trouble with the form instances, it's better to use `UpdateView` instead of the `FormView` (Be sure to import `UpdateView` first)

```
class IndustryView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'ImpactCheck/industry.html'
    model = QuizTakers
    fields = ['industry']
    success_url = '/1'
    def get_object(self):
        return QuizTakers.objects.get(pk=self.request.session.get('obj_id'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['company_name'] = QuizTakers.objects.get(pk=self.request.session.get('obj_id'))
        return ctx
```

We use the `get_context_data` method since you need the `company_name` in your template. The `get_object` method in this view, tells django which object is to be updated. By default, it grabs the `pk` from the url (as a url parameter). But since we store our id in the session, we need to explicitly define this function.

Also, since we switched to `UpdateView`, you no longer need the `QTIndustryForm` either.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer! When you say 'you don't need to manually define the form_valid method', where should the save section come? When I completely remove the form_valid section the industry does not save to the DB. When I add back in the form_valid section it does save.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually changed my answer by a lot. I tried running the last one on my local machine and it didn't seem to work for some reason. This works though

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer if it has helped you?